# Positive samples are not being created

Tags: opencv, object-detection, createsamples

I am trying to create a Haar-classifier for object detection and I am following the next tutorial for Mac:
https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training

When I get to fire step 5. I get the following output on my terminal with no positive samples created:

opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 75 -h 75 -img ./positive_images/63.jpg -bg tmp -vec samples/63.jpg.vec -num 16
opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 75 -h 75 -img ./positive_images/77.jpg -bg tmp -vec samples/77.jpg.vec -num 16
opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 75 -h 75 -img ./positive_images/88.jpg -bg tmp -vec samples/88.jpg.vec -num 16
opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 75 -h 75 -img ./positive_images/89.jpg -bg tmp -vec samples/89.jpg.vec -num 16
opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 75 -h 75 -img ./positive_images/76.jpg -bg tmp -vec samples/76.jpg.vec -num 16
...

Something I should mention is that when I had OpenCV 3.4 it worked but now I have OpenCV 4. If you think that might be the issue please let me know how can I install OpenCV 3.4 instead because I have tried by I always end up installing OpenCV 4 instead.

Comment: Do you see a directory named `positive_images` in the current directory from where you run the script?

Comment: Yes. I have that one and the negative_images one as well.